# Execute code every X seconds, but break immediately on event?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am looking for a way to execute some code every X seconds but if an event occurs during the X seconds, break immediately.

Originally I had a while loop with a sleep statement at the end. However this was problematic because if the code was sleeping, I couldnt stop the code immediately and had to wait until the sleep had finished.

Is there any simple way I can execute then sleep, but interrupt this sleep on an event?

EDIT: Opted for a condition variable with notify_all().

Comment: Show us the code. Btw I guess you want something like [`boost::thread::interrupt()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have already found out an answer but conditional wait on mutex is the best solution here. You can essentially lock the mutex and throw it in a wait condition object along with some timeout. Some other thread can then signal/notify your thread using the same (shared) wait condition object. If nobody notifies/signals the mutex within specified timeout, the wait will simply come out of sleep.

The advantage of this interruptible sleep is that it's not a busy waiting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can interrupt sleep but you could have your code sleeping in shorter intervals and check for a signal regularly.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;
  unsigned Y = 100;
  unsigned X = 1;
  bool signaled = false;
  while (!signaled)
  {
    // Do Stuff every X seconds
    high_resolution_clock::time_point const p = high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - p).count() < 
      duration_cast<milliseconds>(std::chrono::seconds(X)).count())
    {
      // Code to check for a signal every Y milliseconds
      if (signaled)
      {
        break;
      }
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(Y));
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

*Note: System depedant clock resolutions; Possible trade-off with respect to CPU load when adjusting signal check frequency (depending on the demand of the signal check code);*

Comment: Hi, ive gone for a notify_all() with a condition variable, but I'm unsure where I should join the thread which has just finished.

Comment: @user997112 That's probably a new question where you should share some code.